# EOF for string or any other alternativ

Tags: c, string

In C, is there any equivalent of EOF for string or any other condition to stop reading the string data in the program?

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: the code that í´m using is in C

Answer (score 0):

The last character in any string is a null (`\0`) character. You can keep reading a string until this.

Here is a simple wordcounting program using this:

```
char string[] = "Hello, World!";
int count = 0;
int i = 0;

while(1) {
    if(string[i++] != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
}

printf("Letter count: %d", count);
```

Comment: that´s not exaclty what i meant ...  i have to read an unkown quantity of strings given by the user